Trouble scanning android emulator for files on maui
I am doing android reader app on maui and stuck on auto finding fb2 and txt files. I've also pushed into storage png and jpg files and program finds it, but not fb2 and txt which are in the same directory.
I've tried using MediaStore:
   public static List<string> GetFilesFromMediaStore(string[] fileExtensions)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        var uri = MediaStore.Files.GetContentUri("external");

        
        var selection = string.Join(" OR ", fileExtensions.Select(ext => $"_data LIKE '%.{ext}'"));

        string[] projection = {
         MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.Data, 
         MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DisplayName 
};

        using (var cursor = Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver.Query(uri, projection, selection, null, null))
        {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.MoveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                    var filePath = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.Data));
                    result.Add(filePath);
                }
                while (cursor.MoveToNext());
            }
        }

        return result;
}

and tried java.io:
public static List<string> GetFilesJavaIO(string rootPath)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();

        var rootDir = new Java.IO.File(rootPath);
        if (!rootDir.Exists() || !rootDir.IsDirectory)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Path is not a directory or doesn't exist: {rootPath}");
            return result;
        }

        var filesAndDirs = rootDir.ListFiles();
        if (filesAndDirs == null) return result;

        foreach (var fileOrDir in filesAndDirs)
        {
            if (fileOrDir.IsDirectory)
            {
                // Рекурсивный вызов для подпапок
                result.AddRange(GetFilesJavaIO(fileOrDir.AbsolutePath));
            }
            else if (fileOrDir.IsFile)
            {
                result.Add(fileOrDir.AbsolutePath);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

but nothing seems to work correctly

You do not have read access to arbitrary file types in arbitrary directories in external storage in modern versions of Android. Please use the Storage Access Framework (e.g., ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT / ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument) and allow the user to choose the content through the system UI.

@CommonsWare it worked, but sad that there is no way to make auto scan. i use readera on my 5 years old phone and it has auto scan, but android there is pretty old i  think
